# Brown Forsyth test across two columns row by row in R

Tags: r

I would like to perform a [brown forsyth test](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lawstat/lawstat.pdf) ([F-test for non-normally distributed data](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35a.htm))  row by row across two columns.

An example of what i am trying to achieve is below: I hope it is clear.

```
D1 <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 10, sd = 5)
D2 <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 15, sd = 6)
D3 <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 20, sd = 5)
D4 <-rnorm(n=50, mean = 15, sd = 7)
Data1 <- data.frame(D1,D2,D3, D4)
medData1<- apply(Data1, 1, median)


A1 <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 15, sd = 6)
A2 <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 10, sd = 5)
A3 <- rnorm(n=50, mean = 10, sd = 7)
A4 <-rnorm(n=50, mean = 20, sd = 5)
Data2 <- data.frame(A1,A2,A3, A4)
medData2<- apply(Data2, 1, median)

meds<-data.frame(medData1,medData2)
> head(meds)
   medData1  medData2
1 15.194196 13.962238
2 15.443147  9.421257
3 16.436454 16.177326
4 10.042506 15.877342
5 14.793970 16.741701
6  9.709235 14.887777
```

Using the median of medData1 and medData2 I would like to see if the assumption that the variances are equal is true or not using a brown forsyth test. I need it to be done row wise as each row is an individual point in the dataset.

I am assuming a loop is maybe the best to make the test loop from one row to the next but i have tried different ways and failed (hence why i am now posting :) )

In my real data - the median of each dataset is calculated from 20 values and i have  572009 observations (rows).

Can you please advise the best way

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), please also read on [asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Thanks

Comment: a few thoughts: (1) [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown%E2%80%93Forsythe_test) Brown-Forsythe is testing homogeneity of variance, not Normality;  (2) B-F test in R from [here](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/HH/html/hovBF.html); (3) if you want to go "row by row", are you seriously considering testing homogeneity of variance on two data points at a time ... ??

Comment: OK, I take #1 back. [this](https://www.xlstat.com/en/solutions/features/welch-and-brown-forsythe-one-way-anova) defines a "Brown-Forsythe F-test" ...

Comment: @BenBolker sorry probably should have explained a little better. for each row i use 20 values to find the median for the value in column 1 and 20 values for the median in column 2. This is repeated for every row as i have 57200 data points. i know that the data is not normal. I wanted to do an F-test but since the data isn't normal i have to find an alternative - which is where the BF tests comes in. i want to compare the variances of the two groups.

Comment: can you please [edit] your question to clarify? Also, it would help to give a description/link to the formulation of the Brown-Forsythe test (not familiar to me, and probably even less so to other SO contributors); in particular, I'm curious how one can possibly do a test based on only one summary statistic from each group ...?

Comment: @BenBolker Sure thing. I hope the update helps. Thanks for the advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown%E2%80%93Forsythe_test), the Brown-Forsythe test is done by performing a 1-way ANOVA on the absolute deviations from the median in each group. You still need all the data, though; if you compute the medians and throw away the original data you'll be stuck.

Set up data:

```
mkdata <- function(meanvec,sdvec,nmvec,n=50) {
    m <- mapply(rnorm,meanvec,sdvec,MoreArgs=list(n=n))
    d <- as.data.frame(m)
    names(d) <- nmvec
    return(d)
}
set.seed(101)
Data1 <- mkdata(c(10,15,20,15),c(5,6,5,7),paste0("D",1:4))
Data2 <- mkdata(c(15,10,10,20),c(6,5,7,5),paste0("A",1:4))
```

This is not necessarily the most efficient approach, but it should work. Basically, we're setting up a little data set composed of the absolute deviations for each group and a grouping factor, fitting a linear model, and extracting the p-value from the summary.

```
testfun <- function(x,y) {
    x <- unlist(x); y <- unlist(y) ## nec if taking data from rows of a data frame
    d <- data.frame(g=factor(rep(1:2,c(length(x),length(y)))),
                    y=c(abs(x-median(x)),y=abs(y-median(y))))
    mod <- lm(y~g,data=d)
    pval <- coef(summary(mod))["g2","Pr(>|t|)"]
    return(pval)
}

res <- rep(NA,nrow(Data1))
for (i in 1:nrow(Data1)) res[i] <- testfun(Data1[i,],Data2[i,])
```

If you need to speed this up the easiest way would be to parallelize it across multiple cores (see e.g. `?parallel::mclapply`). You might save a bit of time as well by storing your data in matrices rather than data frames ...

PS we could replace our `testfun` (almost) by `car::leveneTest` (which does almost the same thing ...)

Comment: Thanks so much.  I will give this a try.

Comment: StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.

Comment: Ben's testfun agrees with leveneTest(y~g, data=d, center=median) in {car} version 3.1.0. Readers beware that bf.test(y~g, d) in {onewatests} version 2.6 disagrees. I checked the code of bf.test and it uses means but the results still did not agree with leveneTest(y~g, data=d, center=mean).